# Unable to grant access to a chatroom to a low reputation user (trying to move a question discussion to chat)

Tags: discussion, chat

I'd like to move the discussion from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63766065/docker-django-gpio-rasbian-buster/63778299) into a chatroom. I created a chatroom (in "Gallery" mode), and under the "Access" tab is a section labelled "Explicit write access", which says:

> Even when this room is read-only or their reputation is too low, these users will be able to talk in this room.

Which sounds like exactly what I want, because the user asking the question has a reputation of 5. Unfortunately, if I try to grant the user write access to the room, I get the "Users must have at least 20 reputation to talk" error.

...which I knew, and is why I'm trying to grant explicit write access because "their reputation is too low".

Is there no way to have a conversation with a low-reputation user outside of comments?

Comment: It doesn't. I'm unclear from that question if (a) it's a documentation bug that nobody has bothered to fix, or (b) if it's an actual operational bug. The [original request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257949/room-owners-should-be-allowed-to-accept-20-rep-users-to-talk-in-a-room) from six years ago appears to be filled with nothing but support for making this work as suggested by the text.

Comment: As the answer to that question states, it was affirmed as intended behavior by a then-employee. The sentence only makes a statement on what users in that list can do, but makes no statement on who can add users to that list. That might change soon, though, given that another employee tagged it as under review, but for now, the current way is by design.

Comment: Only moderators can grant access to <20 rep users